# Development APNs certificate not being uploaded

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When uploading the p12 file and password, the form closes and nothing changes. There's no error messages displayed either. Any ideas?

Comment: Having the same issue

Comment: Have you tried using incognito window / other browsers? Also check if there are any errors in the Developer's console (F12), then file a ticket / bug on Firebase Support.

Comment: Experiencing the same issue for uploading development APNS cert. Asking for password (while no password was given for the cert). Works for production APNS certificate though.

Comment: I've tried using incognito mode, other browsers nothing helped. no errors also.

Comment: same here. In developer's console, it shows "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()"

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems. Later I found that I was uploading the wrong certificate. I was trying to upload the app development certificate instead of the APN one. Then I try to create a new APN certificate on apple developer website and upload this new certificate. This time, it works fine.

Well maybe this just works for me, but anyway, hope this can be helpful :)